# データフレームに新しいカラムを追加し、計算をおこないたいです

Tags: python, csv

画像のような売上データに対し、「評価」というカラムを追加して、「A,B,C」の評価をしたいと考えています。

```
for index, id in enumerate(data['ID'].unique()):
    sm_data = data[data['ID'] == id]

"カラムを作成"
    sm_data['評価'] = 'A'

    result = list(sm_data["売上"])

    for i in result:
    
    if i < 20000:
        sm_data['評価'].append('A')
    
    elif i < 8000:
        sm_data['評価'].append('C')
        
    else: sm_data['評価'].append('B')
```

エラーコードで下記のように表示されます。

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

どのようにすれば、追加したカラムに評価を加えることができますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**売上データ**

[image: 売上データ]

Comment: @metropolis
先ほどはご指摘ありがとうございました。
質問を更新したらコメントが削除されてしまいました。
大変失礼いたしました。

Answer (score 2):

以下は [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map) を使う場合です。

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'ID': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
  'name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
  '月': ['2017/1/1', '2017/2/1', '2017/3/1', '2017/4/1', '2017/5/1',
         '2017/1/1', '2017/2/1', '2017/3/1', '2017/4/1', '2017/5/1'],
  '売上': [9786, 8464, 20291, 13130, 33974, 6459, 5586, 13392, 8666, 22423],
}) 

df['評価'] = df['売上'].map(
               lambda x: 'A' if x > 20000 else ('C' if x < 8000 else 'B'))

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)
print(df)

=>
   ID name        月    売上  評価
0  10    A  2017/1/1   9786    B
1  10    A  2017/2/1   8464    B
2  10    A  2017/3/1  20291    A
3  10    A  2017/4/1  13130    B
4  10    A  2017/5/1  33974    A
5  20    B  2017/1/1   6459    C
6  20    B  2017/2/1   5586    C
7  20    B  2017/3/1  13392    B
8  20    B  2017/4/1   8666    B
9  20    B  2017/5/1  22423    A
```

Comment: 「map」を使ったコードは見たことはあるのですが、このように使うんですね。
大変勉強になりました。lamdaの使い方がいまいちわからないのでもっと勉強します。泣
ご回答いただき誠にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

`Series`に存在しない`append()`を呼び出しているのでエラーになっています。

条件付きで「評価」列の値を更新する場合は、以下のようにします（他にも方法はありますが）。

```py
sm_data.loc[sm_data["売上"] < 8000, '評価'] = 'C'
```

それから、if分がおかしいです。

```
    if i < 20000:
        sm_data['評価'].append('A')
    
    elif i < 8000:
```

これでは8000より小さい値でも最初のif文内に入るので、`A`になります。

追記：「売り上げが20000を超えたら」という条件であれば、以下の3行で十分です。

```py
sm_data['評価'] = 'B'
sm_data.loc[sm_data["売上"] > 20000, '評価'] = 'A'
sm_data.loc[sm_data["売上"] < 8000, '評価'] = 'C'
```

Comment: こちらご対応いただきありがとうございます。
<sm_data.loc[sm_data["売上"] > 20000, '評価'] = 'A'> このように指定できること初めて知りました。とても完結でわかりやすいです。
たいへん勉強になりました。